# WebViews in ViewPager randomly load pages

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I took the viewPager example from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)
and its working fine with listViews.

I changed it up a bit to work with webviews.

I removed the listView methods and i changed the class to "extends Fragment" and i added a webview to the fragment layout
this is where i load the url

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ((WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView1)).loadUrl(imgURL);
}
```

the methods gets called when i swipe to a new fragment but the image loads on a random fragment. It loads on one fragment and you need to swipe to other fragments until it loads on another fragment randomly but it never appears on two fragments.

I assume its because the ArrayListFragment is static so i tried to make it not static and create new objects in the getItem method but it resulted in the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently getActivity() was the culprit and i solved the loading with

```
WebView wv = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl(...);
```

int the onCreateView() method.